# Не работает скрипт подключения к FTP Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, integration-services

Добрый день!
При переносе пакета SSIS на новый сервер Windows 2012, sql 2016, Vusial Studio 2015 (Windows 7, sql 2012, Vusial Studio 2013), перестал работать скрипт подключения к FTP. При подключении используется библиотека AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client. Она указана в References, файл лежит в необходимой папке.
Скрипт выдает ошибку, именно в месте обращения к библиотеке:

```
using (FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient())
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
> ```

Я попробовала подключить другую библиотеку BytesRoad.NetSuit_2_0 , но ошибка точно такая же. На старом сервере все работает отлично.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что вы в Script Component используете стороннюю библиотеку *AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client*.
**Решение** - поместите вашу библиотеку в GAC на новом сервере.
**Объяснение**. Механизм выполнения SSIS пакетов таков - берется пакет и выполняется ядром SSIS. При этом ядро должно найти все библиотеки, на которые ссылаются Script Tasks. Сторонние библиотеки не вкомпилируются в пакеты, библиотека должна резолвится -- или из GAC (что IMHO проще), или ссылкой в .config файле ядра SSIS.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я добавила библиотеку в GAC - команда была выполнена успешно "Assembly successfully added to the cache". А затем выбрала в References путь к новой папке с библиотекой на  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL. Ошибка осталась прежней(

Comment: Тогда вложите полный текст ошибки, как он пишется в логе SSIS или SSMS.